# Can facebook app get approved if not using Facebook login and call back url?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook php sdk v4 to post as admin to my own fan page. No other user will use this app.

The script will run under cron job and post three products a day. I created a new facebook app and use graph API explorer to get short live access token. I need extended permission on "manage_pages and "publish_actions". Tested using test app and working fine.

Now I need to get approval of the app. However, I do not use Facebook login and there is no call back url, which is required in the form of approval. Since this is run under background, Facebook team can not test the app.

How to get the actual app approved and run on my server?

```
$api_key = 'xxxxx';
$api_secret = 'yyyyy';
$page_id = 'zzzzz';
$accessToken='aaaaa';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($api_key, $api_secret);
$session = new FacebookSession($accessToken);

$access_token = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/' . $page_id,  array( 'fields' => 'access_token' ) ))
    ->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// save access token in variable for later use  
$access_token = $access_token['access_token'];

$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'name' => 'product title',
    'link' => 'product image url',
    'caption' => 'web store name',
    'message' => 'product description and url',
  ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: If no user is ever going to use it except you then there is no reason to submit it for review

Comment: Thanks! I was confused with the public apps. Working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't need to get the application reviewed if you are going to be the only person using it** . Even if you need to enable access to the app for few members in the team, you can add them as app testers to the app (in roles section) , so that even they can also use the app with out review .

the review action is for ensuring the quality of the app to general public.  but all the actions including open graph stories can be published on behalf of app owner/developer or testers accounts with out review .

**note :** for your purpose you might not want to change the application from development mode . more details on [development mode and app roles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/) .

Comment: Thanks! I was confused with the public apps. Working now!